Choosing between attending conference or PhD interview when a little time gap between both
I have completed my master's and currently have a one-year contract as a junior research fellow while I apply for PhDs in Europe. Recently, I applied for both a conference and PhD position.
The PhD position is at a good institute. The project offered interests me, and I am scheduled for a first-round interview on January 13th. However, I think it will take me substantial time to prepare for this interview, as I have to brush up on the old work and think through how to clearly convey the ideas.
The conference theme matches my current work, and takes place January 7th-10th, though it is 1000 km away from the interview. I am not sure whether I should go. This will be the first time I will present a poster, and it would be helpful in my PhD applications. But posters also require time to be prepared. My guide is saying to focus on the PhD interview as I haven't got any PhD position yet.
Now based on level of interview difficulty and importance in longer-term, what should I do? Skip the conference to prepare for the PhD interview? I feel like I can attend both, but I might be wrongly estimating the seriousness of preparation. Also, in this period  I also have some 6-7 PhD application deadlines.

The last sentence in your question (added in edits) is easy to miss, but it's important: "there are 6-7 other positions with deadlines in this period that I could be applying to". Your question focuses on "should I skip the conference to prepare for the PhD interview?", but if you'd asked "how should I divide my time between preparing for this interview, going to this conference, and applying for more positions", you might have gotten a different range of answers.


Now based on level of Interview difficulty and importance in longer-term, what should i do? Leave the conference and prepare for PhD interview to attend both. I feel like I can attend both, I might be wrongly estimating the seriousness of preparation.

Answering purely this question, you do not (should not) need these four days to prep for an interview so badly that you skip a professional opportunity to "prepare."

Do you mean the conference as a professional opportunity to prepare? Please see I have added some edits.

@Mirae None of your details are really relevant, except the PhD application deadlines.

@Mirae And no, I mean before an interview, you are not studying for it 8 hours a day for days on end.

But this is my first interview, and I must be prepared at my best. I have to review the details of some projects and the relevant softwares I used years ago. Also, PhD applications take time, I have to read papers of faculty offering project to get better idea, are you considering these?

@Mirae Surprisingly, when you came to ask Academia.SE about academia, people familiar with academia come to answer your question.

So your advice is to attend both right? Because these shouldn't take that time.

@Mirae Yes, but ultimately this is a question only you can decide.

A three day gap between events is not at all unusual during your PhD. You might just as well get used to it now.
Don’t let either opportunity pass. You have nothing to lose but a bit of sleep.

Sleep... I think I remember what that is...

I can't see any reason not to do both. The conference might even help you prepare for the interview. But you might ask if there is any chance that you could do the interview at the conference location in case the department will have some people there.
Some conferences are also good places to look for other opportunities for doctoral study.
I'll also note that an inexperienced PI carries risk. You will need to evaluate them as much as they do you. And don't end your search elsewhere until you are sure.

Attend the conference. Unless it is in a completely unrelated field, your preparation will pay off as preparation for the Ph.D. interview as well. You can't really cram for a Ph.D. interview anyway. You have more than enough time to remind yourself of what you did, the interview is not an exam.
Do read up on the work of the faculty offering the project, but you can do this on the way to the conference and back, while you're sitting by your poster at low periods, and any other time at the conference when you're not meeting people or doing something else that's more beneficial to your goals (in your own judgment) than preparing for this one interview.
PS. The last sentence in your question contains important information: There are other Ph.D. positions with looming deadlines that you consider applying to. By all means, apply! If it were me I would do that instead of cramming for the interview, and still go to the conference. Or focus at the ones you really want. But of course it's your call at the end.

Seriously, @Mirae? Your time management is your own responsibility. But while you are at the conference, some conference-related activities (meeting people, listening to interesting talks) are more useful to you than rereading your own old work; some are less important (e.g. listening to a plenary on an unrelated topic), and you can use the time for your interview preparation. You'll have to develop and use your own judgment as to which is which.

Going against the grain here a bit, but I'd say that if you feel that half a week is too close for comfort, it's fine to ask for another date for the interview. If you feel that you need a couple of days after an opportunity to present your work to prepare for the interview I'm sure they will accommodate. Ask them if there is the possibility to do the PhD interview a week or so later and they will probably find you a date that better suits your schedule, and then your can realize both opportunities without having to worry about doing one of them half baked.
